# HttpPostedFileBase on Apple products

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, safari

I'm working with ASP.NET MVC and upload via HttpPostedFileBase class.

Everything works fine but on Safari under Mac and IPAD my HttpPostedFileBase object is null.
Moreover I tried Safari under Windows and it works.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase uploadedFile)
    // uploadedFile is null but only under apple products
```

[Edit] I'm using blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload on client side

[Edit] Javascript code

```
function initFileUpload(elem) {
        elem.fileupload({
            autoUpload: true,
            inputTarget: null,
            formData: {
            },
            acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png|avi|mp4|ogg)$/i,
            dataType: 'json',
            add: function (e, data) {
                data.submit();
            },
            url: '@Url.Action("UploadFile")',
            done: function (e, data) {
                $('#loadingModal').modal('hide');
                if (data.result.statusCode == 200) {
                    $(".uploadFile").val(data.result.url);
                    $(".uploadFileViewer").text(data.result.fileName);
                } else {
                    alert(data.result.status);
                }
            },
            fail: function (e, data) {
                $('#loadingModal').modal('hide');
                alert('Upload failed !');
            }
        });
        elem.bind('fileuploadsubmit', function (e, data) {
            $('#loadingModal').modal({
                show: true,
                backdrop: 'static',
                keyboard: false
            });
            return (true);
        });
        elem.bind('fileuploadprogress', function (e, data) {
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);

            $("#loadingBar").attr('style', "width:" + progress + "%;");
        });
    }
```

Thanks